# How to set Seaborn/Matlplotlib scatterplot markers to corresponding images/photos?

Tags: python, pandas, image, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create a scatterplot with Seaborn that would have small thumbnail images as markers instead of the default markers (circles, crosses, squares etc.). Each image is different and must follow unique IDs that run through my entire Pandas dataframe.

I can create the plots just fine with normal markers, but I would like to see my small 24x24 thumbnail images in the scatterplot. This would enable me to visually confirm my prior analysis steps are not garbage. My dataframe structure is as follows:

```
uniqueID    x    y    path                        kmeans
1           3.4  2.1  'C:\Images\imageid1.jpg'    7
2           0.2  5.3  'C:\Images\imageid2.jpg'    4
3           4.0  3.9  'C:\Images\imageid3.jpg'    7
...
```

When defining the scatterplot with `sns.scatterplot()`, I've tried reading the paths as markers, I've also tried reading the images first with PIL to a new column in the dataframe and reading these as markers, but these approaches do not work. Seaborn's own documentation doesn't show how to do scatterplots with thumbnail images as markers. Here's my relevant code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
sns.scatterplot(
    x="x", y="y",
    hue="kmeans",
    palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 8),
    data=df,
    marker=df['path'],
    legend="full",
    alpha=0.30
)
```

I expect to create a scatterplot where each marker is replaced by its corresponding picture.

Comment: There is no API for images/files as markers; neither in seaborn, nor matplotlib. So what you need to do is to loop over the dataframe and create a new image at the position where you want to show it.

Answer (score -3):

**I think it's markers not maker.

you can create a dictionary where each X value is associated with path.and in makrker you can give path of that dict.

like this==>

```
          data  = { "3.4":"C:\Images\imageid1.jpg",..........}
          sns.scatterplot(......
                          markers=data)
```